# Proof of $\forall \vec{u} \in V 0\vec{u} = \vec{0}$

Tags: linear-algebra

in class the teacher gave us a proof

But I would like to see another

$\forall \vec{u} \in V$(V is a vector space over a filed K)
$0\vec{u} = \vec{0}$

My Proof:

$0\vec{u} = 0\vec{u}$
$0\vec{u} + \vec{0} = 0\vec{u}$
$0\vec{u} + \vec{0} = (0+0)\vec{u}$
$0\vec{u} + \vec{0} = 0\vec{u} + 0\vec{u}$
by cancellation law
$\vec{0} = 0\vec{u}$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**An easier way**

$$0u=(0+0)u=0u+0u\implies 0u=0.$$

I let you justify every equalities.

Comment: To me that looks more like "exactly the same way", only with slightly fewer details filled in.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Yes and no... It precisely doesn't need more detail than that. But of course, the proof is the same.

Comment: Thank you, I was not convinced about 0u = 0u